# Making the vertical scrollbar visible and horizontal scroll bar visible

Tags: android, scroll, android-tablelayout

i'm developing an android application in which i need 3 table layouts first and last should scroll in horizontal and middle one should scroll in both directions and i need to add rows to those table layouts dynamically .

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a layout in this way,

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_layout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table_layout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_layout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```